# Firebase - How to unlink a custom provider from a account

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Firebase plugin in Unity for authentication. I have an account that authenticates with the standard providers (email, apple, etc) and can also link their Twitch account. The Twitch account linking is done through a custom provider. This is tracked in a separate table to keep track of which accounts are linked to Twitch.

The problem I am having is with unlinking the Twitch account. Custom providers don't have a provider id so from the client I'm unable to unlink it.

I've checked `FirebaseUser.ProviderData` to see if anything was there to maybe pass into the unlink call. I've also passed in the provider id I supplied the credential with, but get this error message: `FirebaseException: User was not linked to an account with the given provider.`

How do I unlink a custom provider?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I believe my issue was not understanding how the custom providers worked well enough. Deleting the entry in the table we keep separately was sufficient enough to un-link the account.

Worth noting when you delete an account you need to ensure you delete your entry too. Also if the account only has custom providers the providers list will be empty. So you can't rely on that if you had been for an anonymous account or things like that.